# Как получить значения из классов и поместить в input?

Tags: javascript

У меня на странице есть несколько элементов span (выводятся в цикле),

```
<span class="options">Текст 1</span>
<span class="options">Текст 2</span>
<span class="options">Текст 3</span>
```

и эти значения нужно вытащить их и поместить в форму в input через запятую. Если таких значений нет, то поместить в input 0

```
<input type="hidden" name="options" value="">
```

Как это сделать через JS?

Answer (score 4):

```js
let texts = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('span.options')).map(el => el.textContent);
let result = texts.length > 0 ? texts.join(',') : 0;
document.querySelector('#test').value = result;
```

```html
<span class="options">Текст 1</span>
<span class="options">Текст 2</span>
<span class="options">Текст 3</span>


<input type="text" name="options" value="" id="test">
```

Comment: спасибо. то что надо

Comment: Галочку рядом с ответом тык 

Answer (score 0):

```js
let input = ''
const elements = document.getElementsByClassName('options')
if (elements.length > 0) {
  input = elements.map(e => e.innerText).join(',')
} else {
  input = '0'
}
// Установите значение тега input
```